# SQL,select max number in Group

Tags: sql-server, numbers, max

I have three tables Student, Grd, Course and I want to select the best grade of each courses and name of students.

Here is my query that returns all students - name and grade - but I want the best grade for each course only.

```
select 
    student.[name], Course.[Name] as course, max((GRD.Number)) as Grade 
from 
    GRD 
join 
    Course on Course.CO_ID = GRD.CO_ID
join 
    Student on Student.ST_ID = GRD.ST_ID
group by 
    course.[Name], Student.[Name]
```

Comment: which flavor of SQL are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL etc.

Comment: I'm using Sql Server

Comment: You can read it here, https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, PostgreSQL, SQL Server or Oracle then you can use the following to solve your problem.

```
select
    student_name,
    course,
    Grade
from
(
    select 
        s.[name] as student_name,
        c.[Name] as course,
        max(g.Number) as Grade, 
        row_number() over (partition by c.[Name] order by max(g.Number) desc) as rnk

    from GRD g
    join Course c
    on c.CO_ID = g.CO_ID

    join Student s
    on s.ST_ID = g.ST_ID

    group by 
        c.[Name],
        s.[Name]
) val
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here, we SELECT student name, course name and his max grade.

> where we join 3 tables and GROUP BY student and course name because we
>   want all details of the best grade of each courses with name of
>   students.
>
> I am using ORDER BY in DESC order for grade to find max grade value
>   and  LIMIT 1 for SELECT top max grade.

```
SELECT
    student.name, Course.Name as course, max((GRD.Number)) as Grade 
FROM GRD 
join 
   Course on Course.CO_ID = GRD.CO_ID
join 
   Student on Student.ST_ID = GRD.ST_ID
GROUP BY student.name, Course.Name
ORDER BY Grade DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: no it's not working.it's returns all students as same as my code

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.